# Why should I use & in this syntax? Problem with SPI register

Tags: embedded, spi

I'm writing a program for SPI communication betweend LPC2109/2 and MCP4921. This is an assignment
on studies. My tutor ask me a question why "&" is necessary in this line? In this line we wait for the end of SPI transmission. Which answer should be right?

```
    #define SPI_SPIF_bm  (1<<7)
    ...
    while((S0SPSR & SPI_SPIF_bm) == 0){}
```

1. We use  "&" as logic AND, for instance: (0000 & 1000) gives us 0000 instead of (0000 | 1000) gives us 1000.
2. Can I use only this line of code: `while((S0SPSR) == 0){}`? In my opinion - no. We need to compare value in register `S0SPSR` with bit SPIF `SPI_SPIF_bm`.

Is there maybe different solution?

**Attachment**
User Manual for LPC2129/01: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10114.pdf

Comment: Are you asking what bit masking means or what the register does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPI peripheral of LPC2109/2 sets different bits of `S0SPSR` depending on the actual event that happens which may depend on external circumstances. For example if there's a write collision on the SPI line it sets the `WCOL` bit instead of `SPIF`.

If you use `while((S0SPSR) == 0){}` it will wait until either a successful transaction or an error happens because it will exit the loop if any of the bits of `S0SPSR` is set.

`while((S0SPSR & SPI_SPIF_bm) == 0){}` only checks if the transaction has completed successfully. It is a good practice to check the error bits too because in case of an error you would stuck in this loop forever as `SPIF` is never goint to be set.

For a robust solution I would go with something like this:

```
while(S0SPSR == 0) {}

if (S0SPSR & SPI_SPIF_bm) { /* SPI_SPIF_bm remains set until data register has not been accessed */
     /* Success, read the data register, return data, etc. */
} else {
     /* Handle error */
}
```

If you are interested in the particular type of the error you need to store `S0SPSR` in a variable in each cycle as those bits are cleared on reading `S0SPSR`. Also you should to add a counter or a more sophisticated timeout solution to the loop to exit if none of the flags are sets in a reasonable period.

You might think these errors would never happen because you have a simple circuit but they do happen in real life and it's worth doing proper error handling.

Comment: Thank You for fast response! Advice with checking error codes is good idea. I will try it:)

Comment: Generally, this is sloppy coding. You should instead have `volatile uint32_t s0spsr=0; while(s0spsr==0) { s0spsr = S0SPSR;} ... if(s0spsr & mask) { ...`. This to avoid reading the register multiple times, unnecessarily. Which can be particularly problematic in the case of SPI, where flags are sometimes cleared by reading it, following by a read of a data register.